# Alamofire add parameters to multi part request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to add prameters to multi part request but without success, any suggestion.

Compiler says value of type 'Any' has no member 'data'

[image]

```
func createRep(_ question: String, type: String, anonymous: Bool, votesRequired: String, firstType: String, firstText: String, firstMedia: UIImage, secondType: String, secondText: String, secondMedia: UIImage, completionHandler: @escaping (APIResult<Any>) -> Void)
  {
    let parameters: Parameters = [
      JSONKey.question.rawValue: question,
      JSONKey.type.rawValue: type,
      JSONKey.anonymous.rawValue: anonymous,
      JSONKey.votesRequired.rawValue: votesRequired,
      JSONKey.firstType.rawValue: firstType,
      JSONKey.firstText.rawValue: firstText,
      JSONKey.firstMedia.rawValue: firstMedia,
      JSONKey.secondType.rawValue: secondType,
      JSONKey.secondText.rawValue: secondText,
      JSONKey.secondMedia.rawValue: secondMedia
    ]

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + keychainService.getToken(),
      "Accept": "application/json"
    ]

    let url = EndPoint.baseUrl.rawValue + EndPoint.reps.rawValue

    let urlRep = try! URLRequest(url: url, method: .post, headers: headers)

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

      for (key, value) in parameters {
        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
      }

      if let firstMediaData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(firstMedia), let secondMediaData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(secondMedia) {
        multipartFormData.append(firstMediaData, withName: "firstMedia", fileName: "firstMedia", mimeType: "image/png")
        multipartFormData.append(secondMediaData, withName: "secondMedia", fileName: "secondMedia", mimeType: "image/png")
      }

      }, with: urlRep, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch (encodingResult) {
        case .success(let value):
          completionHandler(APIResult.success(value))
        case .failure(let error):
          completionHandler(APIResult.failure(error))
        }
      }
    )

}
```

Comment: Is this another case where a value of type `Any` has to be cast to the actual type? E.g. `value as? String`  ?

Comment: @MartinR key is string and value is string everytime I guess

Comment: `Parameters` is a typealias for `[String: Any]` and not `[String: String]`, as is described in the [Alamofire 4.0 migration guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md) (see also [the source of `ParameterEncoding`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift#L45)). So when iterating over `parameters` above, the type of `value` is `Any`, which must be converted to `String` prior to accessing the `.data(using:)` method of `String`.

Comment: You'll find similar problems with a search for "[swift] value of type any has no member"

Comment: @MartinR thanks it works. ok got it, also is this ok to pass POST param and headers like I did?

Comment: I cannot comment on that, I have never used Alamofire so far.